# I have a login page. I want to put more than one action in form, or there is another solution

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a login page and I have a php & javascript page. I want to link form to javascript and php
code html loin page

```
<form action="INDEX.PHP" method="POST" class="two">
    <div>
        <button class="yeu"  id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="validate();validatewoman();validateuser();">login</button>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="14">
    </div>
    <div id="user" style="color: black; font-size: 20px; text-align: left;">
        <pre style="color: black; font-size: 20px; text-align: left; display: none;"></pre>
</form>
```

php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','login');
if(!$conn){
    echo "data base error";
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO login_table(login) VALUES ('$username')";
   if(!mysqli_query($conn , $sql)){
       echo 'error: '. mysqli_error($conn);
} 
}
?>
```

javascript

```
function validate(){
    var user_one = document.getElementById("username").value;
    if (
        user_one=== "578815452122"
    ){
    else{
document.write = "user error" ; 
    };

};
```

Comment: Ok. Does something not work? Do you get errors? Your validate function in JS is visible for everyone, so if somebody were to open that file they could see the 578815452122

Comment: Well, I don't care for others to see it, because this is not a password

Comment: Probably better to use something like: `window.alert('user error');` instead of `document.write = 'user error';`. For over a decade `document.write` has been labelled suboptimal practice and usage thereof advised against.

Comment: "I want to link form to javascript and php" - what does that mean? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: To be fair, if you don't know that the `onsubmit` event listener exists, it's pretty hard to think your way around this kind of architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onsubmit` **Event Listener**, like this:

```
const myform = document.getElementsByClassName('two')[0];

function validate (e) { ... }

myform.addEventListener('submit', validate);
```

When someone tries to submit your form, the event listener will detect the `submit` event and run the `validate()` function.

The form will be submitted *only after* the function has run.

---

**N.B.** When declaring your `validate()` function, you should have the `event object` specifically named as a parameter (eg. `function validate (event) {...}` or `function validate (e) {...}`), such that at any point where you would like the form to *not* submit, you can invoke `event.preventDefault();` or `e.preventDefault();`.

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: please write onsubmit="what i write"

Comment: You can either use: `myform.onsubmit = validate();` or (probably better practice) `myform.addEventListener('submit', validate);`. For more info on `addEventListener()`, see: [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)